# Dual wielding with the weapon master passive

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

[image]

When dual wielding and using the weapon master passive, does the off hand weapon receive a benefit from the passive? For example, if I'm using two maces does it increase my total chance to critical by 20% or does it increase each individual weapon's chance to crit by 10%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the tooltip says is, if you wear a mace in your main hand then you get 10% crit chance. So each attack (doesn't matter if it's your main or offhand has an additional 10% chance to crit).
When you wear a mighty weapon in your main hand, each hit gives you 3 fury. Also if your off hand is a dagger.

Comment: Ah reading failure, didn't even notice it specified the main hand.

Comment: happens to the best :)

Comment: My excuse is that I didn't actually sleep last night, instead opting to beat act 1 on inferno.