# I've captured some Great Prophets, now what?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

I've managed to capture two great prophets, but they aren't the same religion as the one I founded. I created Shinto, but now I have a Great Prophet from Buddhism and one from Confucianism.

What can I do with these units? Is there a point to using them to spread different religions to my city? They don't seem to be able to build the Holy Site tile improvement that my own great prophets can create.

Comment: As far as I can tell, capturing an enemy Great Prophet just prevents them from trying to bomb your territory with their religion. They are, in all other uses, worthless as far as I've been able to tell.

Comment: I thought so too, but then one of the three I have loitering in my area was able to build a monument. I'm not sure why...

Comment: At least in MP game you could build with enemy great prophet, if he haven't spread his religion yet (4/4).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind is that any major religion is superior to no religion at all. Yes, it gives a bonus to your opponent, but it gives a larger bonus to your city. Therefore, its advisable to use these GPs to spread religion to cities that do not have, and are unlikely to get, Shinto. Island colonies far from other cities are the best example. They would not otherwise get a religion, so it can be wise to spread buddhism or confucianism there.

Finally, look at the benefits provided by those religions. If you have a specialty city, it may be useful to add a specialty religion. For example, if you have a pure production city, and Buddhism gives the 15 percent production bonus, it may be wise to spread Buddhism there in order to get said bonus.

Comment: That's an interesting point, I wasn't positive that the non-founder civ's got the city bonus.

Comment: That is why its called a "Follower" bonus. Cause the followers get it :).

Comment: You seem to assume I read much more than I actually do. I'm a programmer, instructions are things that happen to other people =P

Comment: I'm a programmer too, so I must remind you: RTFM ;).

Comment: Sort of a running them with me sadly: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69841/dual-wielding-with-the-weapon-master-passive

Answer (score 16):

Great Prophets can be expended to construct the "Holy Site" tile improvement, which can be worked for faith.

Faith is agnostic, so it doesn't matter what religious flavor of prophet constructs the tile improvement. Since only two non-faith-purchased buildings produce faith (shrine + temple), you may find the smattering of extra faith useful.

Comment: Note that you can only create a Holy Site if the Great Prophet has all of his "Spread Religion" uses available. It's likely that if you captured those prophets, they've already spread religion at least once and thus cannot create a Holy Site.

Answer (score 6):

A great use of Great Prophets, which can only be taken advantage of by Sweden, is gifting them to city-states to gain 90 influence. This can be incredibly helpful when you have a particularly aggressive enemy who sends great prophets in droves.

Answer (score 1):

As other said, sometimes their religion can be usefull for some city.
Eg. if it allows religious building and you are generating enough faith, you could convert some of your cities, build that building and reconvert back (if done in middle of your religion, one city will be converted relatively quickly).

Another use is: You are pushing your religion against another and gain GP from third. You can now convert some of their cities to that third religion, thus removing part of their preassure while keeping yours.